# A special ternary condition in apex (safe navigation operator)

Tags: apex, conditional, ternary-operator

I've seen this somewhere, sometime before but I can't remember how it's used and I can't find anything about it online (Probably because I don't know what to search for). So please help me understand how to use this and also if you link a reference on the official documentation that would be great.

```
Boolean someVal = true;
String someString = someVal .? 'a value'
// results in someString = 'a value'

Boolean someVal = false;
String someString = someVal .? 'a value'
// results in someString = null
```

So it looks similar or maybe exactly like this code and I think it returns a null if the condition isn't true and returns 'a value' if the condition is true. Please let me know in the comments if I need to add clarification. Thanks!

Comment: The syntax you're using suggests it's the new [safe navigation operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm)

Comment: @DerekF thanks much! That's exactly what I was looking for. Would you mind posting your answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you're looking for is the [safe navigation operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm) introduced in Winter '21 (API v50.0)

It's the reverse of what you thought it was, `?.`, and it helps us deal with nulls in a very compact fashion (as opposed to the previous null checks that we had to pepper all over the place).

Both of your examples would end up holding `'a value'`, because the variable you're testing has a defined value (false != null).

If that's not quite what you're looking for, then the next match would be the standard *ternary operator*, which has a syntax of `<boolean expression> ? <value if true> : <value if false>` such as `Integer myInt = (2 + 2) > 3 ? 1 : -1;`.